# Removing lines containing duplicate regex strings

Tags: regex, grep

I am sorry if this has been ask before but unfortunately there are so many questions about this kind of thing and although they are all related so many situations that apply to one instance may not apply to another so here goes my problem.

I have a file with the output of a pdfgrep of a regular expression containing quite a few lines of output.  The way the text file is formatted is as follows:

```
/path/to/file_1/containing/regex/string regex_string_1
/path/to/file_1/containing/regex/string regex_string_1
/path/to/file_1/containing/regex/string regex_string_1
/path/to/file_2/containing/regex/string regex_string_1
/path/to/file_2/containing/regex/string regex_string_2
/path/to/file_3/containing/regex/string regex_string_2
/path/to/file_3/containing/regex/string regex_string_2
/path/to/file_3/containing/regex/string regex_string_3
/path/to/file_3/containing/regex/string regex_string_3
/path/to/file_3/containing/regex/string regex_string_3
/path/to/file_3/containing/regex/string regex_string_3
```

While pdfgrep did a great job at isolating the information I was attempting to pull from the files there are unfortunately a large number of duplicate regex strings.  Normally removing duplicate lines would not be a problem for me but the issue I am having here is that while the regex string that was pulled from the original files is a duplicate it may have come from a completely different file.  I only want to have the regex that I did the original pdfgrep for to appear one time in the list.  I want to remove any duplicate entries of that string as well as the associated path.  How can I do this?

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/q/1476659/763386) and add expected result.

Answer (score 1):

To remove lines ending in duplicate values replace

```
([^\s]+\s(.*\n))([^\s]+\s\2)+
```

With

```
\2
```

I am assuming with this based on your example input that we can use the first space in a given line to delimit the boundary between the regex which should be checked for duplicates and the rest of the string. If this assumption is wrong you can modify the part `[^\s]+\s` to be any valid regex that matches the first (non duplicate) part of your string.

The first set of parentheses matches the first line which we will keep.

The second set of parentheses matches the string which we want to check as a duplicate values.

In the third set we check again for a string followed by a space followed by the same duplicate string which we captured in the 2nd set of parentheses.

The `+` checks for this multiple times.

`\2` replaces the entire match with just the duplicated string.

Comment: I'm not sure they want to remove duplicate lines, I think they want to remove lines that contain duplicate *regex*, for example keep line  and remove lines 2, 3 and 4. They are not duplicate but contain same regex.

Comment: @Toto Thanks for the feedback. I have modified my answer to hopefully address the question a little better.

Comment: It seems better but we don't know as OP didn't add clarifications about their needs. You should add the tool you are using for these match/replace.

Comment: @Toto if the OP comes back and clarifies I may need to update it. Hopefully my answer will come in helpful to anyone else searching for something similar also. For the search and replace I am using Sublime Text.

Answer (score 0):

**SEARCH:**  `^(.*)(\r?\n\1)+$`

**REPLACE BY:** `\2\r\1\r`

OR

**SEARCH:**   `^(.*)(\r?\n\1)+$`

**REPLACE WITH:**  `\1`

**OR**

FIND: `(?<=|^)([^,]*)(,\1)+(?=,|$)`

**OR**

FIND: `^(.*?)$\s+?^(?=.*^\1$)`